# erlang gen_statem: error bad_return_from_state_function

Tags: erlang, fsm

I got a strange problem. I got this FSM (**The content of the code is not so impotent, so I removed it and now you can look only on the structure**):

```
start_link() ->
  gen_statem:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).


init([]) ->
  io:format ("init", []),
  Data={1},
  {ok, packetsDeliver, Data}.


callback_mode() ->
  [state_functions, state_enter].


packetsDeliver(enter, _OldState, Data) ->
  io:format ("Key1", []),
  {keep_state, Data};

packetsDeliver(info, _OldState, Data) ->
  io:format ("Key2", []),
  {keep_state, Data};


packetsDeliver(cast, _PacketData, Data) ->
  io:format ("Key3", []),
      {next_state, allPacketsDelivered, Data}.

allPacketsDelivered(enter, _OldState, Data) ->
  io:format ("Key4", []),
  {next_state, packetsDeliver , Data}.
```

I tried couple of things without any successes, I thought that writing

```
{next_state, packetsDeliver , Data}.
```

will deliver me the the state:

```
packetsDeliver(enter, _OldState, Data)
```

But instead I got this error:

```
exception exit: {bad_return_from_state_function,
                       {next_state,packetsDeliver,{1}}}
     in function  gen_statem:loop_event_result/9 (gen_statem.erl, line 1165)
     in call from proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3 (proc_lib.erl, line 247)
3> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 27-Jul-2019::23:53:35 ===
** State machine test terminating
** Last event = {cast,1}
** When server state  = {allPacketsDelivered,{1}}
** Reason for termination = error:{bad_return_from_state_function,
                                      {next_state,packetsDeliver,{1}}}
** Callback mode = [state_functions,state_enter]
** Stacktrace =
**  [{gen_statem,loop_event_result,9,[{file,"gen_statem.erl"},{line,1165}]},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]
```

Another question/problem is that I don't know why the state

```
packetsDeliver(enter, _OldState, Data) ->
  io:format ("Key1", []),
  {keep_state, Data};
```

is delivering me to packetsDeliver(info, _OldState, Data) 
when I do keep_state?

Comment: Do you get this crash after start_link() or some event was casted to the FSM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at what your State `enter` function returns for `packetsDeliver`:

```
packetsDeliver(enter, _OldState, Data) ->
  io:format ("Key1", []),
  {keep_state, Data};   %% <====== HERE
```

Now look at what your State `cast` function returns for `packetsDeliver`:

```
packetsDeliver(cast, _PacketData, Data) ->
  io:format ("Key3", []),
  {next_state, allPacketsDelivered, Data}.  %% <===== HERE
```

Now look at what your State `enter` function returns for `allPacketsDelivered`:

```
allPacketsDelivered(enter, _OldState, Data) ->
  io:format ("Key4", []),
  {next_state, packetsDeliver , Data}.  %% <==== HERE
```

The State `enter` function for `allpacketsDelivered` should return a tuple that is similar to the  State `enter` function for `packetsDelivered`, e.g. `{keep_state, ...}` not `{next_state, ...}`.

From [the docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#type-state_callback_result), these are the allowed return values for a State `enter` function:

```
state_callback_result(ActionType) = 
    {keep_state, NewData :: data()} |
    {keep_state,
     NewData :: data(),
     Actions :: [ActionType] | ActionType} |
    keep_state_and_data |
    {keep_state_and_data, Actions :: [ActionType] | ActionType} |
    {repeat_state, NewData :: data()} |
    {repeat_state,
     NewData :: data(),
     Actions :: [ActionType] | ActionType} |
    repeat_state_and_data |
    {repeat_state_and_data, Actions :: [ActionType] | ActionType} |
    stop |
    {stop, Reason :: term()} |
    {stop, Reason :: term(), NewData :: data()} |
    {stop_and_reply,
     Reason :: term(),
     Replies :: [reply_action()] | reply_action()} |
    {stop_and_reply,
     Reason :: term(),
     Replies :: [reply_action()] | reply_action(),
     NewData :: data()}
```

Note that `{next_state, ...}` is not one of the allowed return values, and that is why you are getting the error `bad_return_from_state_function`.  The [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#Module:handle_event-4) also say:

> **When the gen_statem runs with state enter calls**, these functions are
>   also called with arguments `(enter, OldState, ...)` during every state
>   change. In this case there are some restrictions on the actions that
>   may be returned: postpone() is not allowed since a state enter call is
>   not an event so there is no event to postpone, and
>   `{next_event,_,_}` is not allowed since using state enter calls should
>   not affect how events are consumed and produced. **You may also not
>   change states from this call. Should you return
>   `{next_state,NextState, ...}` with `NextState =/= State` the
>   gen_statem crashes.** Note that it is actually allowed to use
>   {repeat_state, NewData, ...} although it makes little sense since you
>   immediately will be called again with a new state enter call making
>   this just a weird way of looping, and there are better ways to loop in
>   Erlang. If you do not update NewData and have some loop termination
>   condition, or if you use {repeat_state_and_data, _} or
>   repeat_state_and_data you have an infinite loop! You are advised to
>   use {keep_state,...}, {keep_state_and_data,_} or keep_state_and_data
>   since changing states from a state enter call is not possible anyway.

======

> Another question/problem is that I don't know why the state
>
> ```
> packetsDeliver(enter, _OldState, Data) ->
>   io:format ("Key1", []),
>   {keep_state, Data};
> ```
>
> is delivering me to packetsDeliver(info, _OldState, Data) when I do
>   keep_state?

What does `when I do keep_state` mean?  I can tell you what it means to anyone reading your question: absolutely nothing.

That info callback doesn't execute when I `do keep_state`.  So that tells you exactly how to fix your code, right?  Wrong.

I'm doing it like this:

```
send_event() ->
    gen_statem:cast(?MODULE, hello).
```

If you do it like this:

```
Pid ! {blah, blah}
```

then the `info` callback for the current state will execute.

Full example:

```
-module(packets).
-behavior(gen_statem).
-compile(export_all).

start_link() ->
    gen_statem:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
    io:format ("init~n"),
    Data=1,
    {ok, packetsDeliver, Data}.  
    %The initial state will be packetsDeliver.
    %And, when you transition to a state, and you 
    %have specified state_enter, then the function
    %State(enter, OldState, Data) will execute, which
    %in this case is packetsDeliver(enter, OldState, Data)

callback_mode() ->
    [state_functions, state_enter].

packetsDeliver(enter, _OldState, Data) ->
    io:format("packetsDeliver enter~n"),
    {keep_state, Data};
packetsDeliver(cast, _Msg, Data) ->
    io:format ("packetsDeliver cast~n"),
    {next_state, allPacketsDelivered, Data};
packetsDeliver(info, _Msg, Data) ->
    io:format("packetsDeliver info~n"),
    {keep_state, Data}.

allPacketsDelivered(enter, _OldState, _Data) ->
    io:format("allPacketsDelivered enter~n"),
    %{next_state, packetsDeliver , Data}.
    {keep_state_and_data, []}.

send_event() ->
    gen_statem:cast(?MODULE, hello).
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs/gen_statem$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(packets).                  
packets.erl:3: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,packets}

2> packets:start_link().                     
init
packetsDeliver enter
{ok,<0.71.0>}

3> Pid = whereis(packets).
<0.71.0>

4> Pid ! hello.
packetsDeliver info
hello

5> packets:send_event().
packetsDeliver cast
ok
allPacketsDelivered enter

6>
```